# Timer Job Not Showing in Central Administrator

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created simple time job, but it's not showing in Central Administrator. If I use PowerShell command then it will show, however I am unable to find it in Central Admin panel.

Comment: How do you deploy the timer job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figure out the problem as whenever deploy the code ,need to restart the Sharepoint Timer Service.